# jquery saving files in dictionary give empty objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save files in a dictionary of data. First the files are stored in a array and then the array is passed on as value in the dictionary. But the problem is when the files are pushed in the array it is doing fine but when it is passed on to the dictionary it gives empty objects.

***jquery:***

```
var file = [];
var jsonarr = [];
//first click saves the files in the array file[]
$(document).on('click', '#lecturesave', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    file.push($('#lecturefile').prop('files')[0]);
});

//second click saves the array in dictionary jsonarr[]
$(document).on('click', '#contentsave', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    for(i=0;i<content.length;i++){
        jsonarr.push({'content': content[i], 'lecture': lecttitle, 'files': file})
    }
    $('#coursecont').val(JSON.stringify(jsonarr))
```

Can someone please help me out with this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example? what is `content` var in `content.length`?

Comment: `content` is an array of user input data. everything is an user input in this which I'm putting in the dictionary at the end.

Comment: if you do `console.log(content.length)` what is the number?

Comment: the length of content is 1.

Answer (score 0):

file is an array you are directly referencing it without specifying index.

jsonarr.push({'content': content[i], 'lecture': lecttitle, 'files': file[i]})
    }
Make the above changes for correct output.

Comment: Can you check and paste the console log by opening the debugger , check for any errors.

Comment: Use console.log on both file and jsonArr, and share that

Comment: I've logged it already but there's no error. Everythings working fine.

Comment: can you see what value is getting filled in jsonarr and file arrays, and can u show that here

Comment: **file:**

`[]

(2) ["", ""]

(2) [File, File]`

**jsonarr:**

`[{"content":"","lecture":["",""],"files":[{},{}]}`

Comment: is file array empty ?